# How to stop event propagation in Blazor Server app

Tags: .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, matblazor

I'm using [Grid.Blazor](https://github.com/gustavnavar/Grid.Blazor/blob/master/docs/blazor_server/Render_button_checkbox_etc_in_a_grid_cell.md) library to render server side grid on Blazor app. One of the column has a button with click event. So when button is clicked then grid row event is also fired along with button click event. I want to stop event propagation and only let button click event fired.

Grid:

```
  <GridComponent @ref="_gridComponent" T="QuickLists" Grid="@_grid"  OnRowClicked="@(async (item) => await ExerciseDetails(item))"></GridComponent>


Action<IGridColumnCollection<QuickExcerciseLists>> columns = c =>
        {
            c.Add().Titled("Actions").RenderComponentAs(typeof(ChildComponent)).SetWidth("5%");
            c.Add(o => o.Name, comparer).Titled("Name").SetWidth("10%");
            c.Add(o => o.Age, comparer).Titled("Age").SetWidth("15%");
            c.Add(o => o.Address, comparer).Titled("Address").RenderComponentAs<MatTooltip>().SetWidth("15%");
        };
```

Custom Column Component :

```
<MatBlazor.MatButton Icon="@MatIconNames.Remove_red_eye" @onclick="@ShowData" @onclick:stopPropagation="true"></MatBlazor.MatButton>
```

I tried passing `@onclick:stopPropagation` in the child button component. But it's given below compile error.

> The component parameter 'onclick' is used two or more times for this
>   component. Parameters must be unique (case-insensitive). The component
>   parameter 'onclick' is generated by the '@onclick:stopPropagation'
>   directive attribute.

I'm running .Net core 3.1.201. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This @onclick:stopPropagation="true" should be fine. You are not using the onclick directive twice. Can't say what is the source of the error...

Comment: yea. the error says '@onclick:stopPropagation' generates `onclick`. So it makes 2 `onclick` events on the control.

Comment: `MatButton` is not a button, is a component, contains several elements. Maybe `MatButton` doesn't support `StopPropagation`. Check code on GitHub, is an open project.

Comment: @daniherrera Yes. You are right. It's working with regular html elements but not with custom elements. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

In case it helps, and to add to the comment @Ivan made for the MatBlazor MatButton/MatIconButton which didn't seem to work for me, I used the following workaround:

```
<div @onclick:stopPropagation="true" @onclick:preventDefault="true">
  <MatButton OnClick="@DoSomething" @ref="MyButton">Do it!</MatButton>
</div>
```

I needed to use both stopPropagation and preventDefault. I had to use the div wrapper as MatButton didn't allow me to add multiple onclicks.

Comment: I have the same problem with nested custom components and your solution works for me!

Comment: This solution also helped my case. I had a MudBlazor `<MudNavGroup>`  tag for which I had already wired an `onclick` event handler.

Comment: if anyone is looking to ignore parent onclick but use hyperlink in Blazor, @onclick:stopPropagation="true" works wonders.

Comment: Worked also with Mudblazor MudDataGrid and row components.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue with an expander. I wanted to be able to click a button inside an expander row without having the row expand. I was able to accomplish this by using **@onmousedown** for my C# code and **onclick** for the window event call

```
 <a class="text-primary" @onmousedown="() => MyModal.Open()" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"> Button </a>
```

Comment: Worked great for me too. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I faced different issue with multiple handlers. Because I was using `@onclick` and `@onshortclick` like this:

```
<div @onclick="ParentClick" style="width:500px;height:300px">

    <h1>parent click</h1>

    <h1 @onshortclick="ChildClick">child with propagation</h1>

    <h1 @onshortclick="ChildClick" 
        @onclick:stopPropagation="true" 
        @onshortclick:stopPropagation="true">child without click</h1>
</div>
```

As you can see the parent has `@onclick` and children have `@onshortclick`.
An in order not to propagate the event up to the parent, you have to `stopPropagate` for both events.

Answer (score 1):

## For those trying to stop scroll propagation

Here's what didn't work for me
(any for itself and all together)

```
@onmousewheel:stopPropagation
@onmousewheel:preventDefault
@onwheel:stopPropagation
@onwheel:preventDefault
@onscroll:stopPropagation
@onscroll:preventDefault
```

Here are two links that describe this bug on github

[Blazor preventDefault with wheel event](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17358)

[Blazor webassembly: @onwheel:preventDefault has no effect](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24932)

## These issues are being postponed since November 2019.

In short, and I'll quote some comments from these links

> Use of preventDefault within scroll-type events (including wheel) is discouraged by browsers because it reduces the responsiveness of the site.

> The recommended alternative is to block default scrolling behaviors using the CSS style `touch-action: none`

## Simple and short workaround

This is suggested by `sergey-su` from the second link I shared.

site.js :

```
window.myUtils = {
    addDefaultPreventingHandler: function (element, eventName) {
        element.addEventListener(eventName, e => e.preventDefault(), { passive: false });
    }
};
```

your razor component :

```
<div @ref=myElementReference>...</div>

@code{
    
    ElementReference? myElementReference = default!;
    
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("myUtils.addDefaultPreventingHandler", myElementReference, "wheel");
    }
}
```

> Possibly blazor does not set the passive option correctly when it adds its event listener. It should disable the scroll optimization by setting passive: false when @on:preventDefault is present for a scrolling event in the razor markup.

## Conclusion

When going with this route you don't need the `@on___:stopPropagation` or `@on___:preventDefault` that I mentioned at the top.

The `@onmousewheel` and `@onwheel` still work just fine.

Go like `sergey-su`'s bug report and workaround if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue with a Table. It seems that now MatBlazor buttons have a way to stop propagation: `OnClickStopPropagation="true"`

Following code works for me, with `MatIconButton` and `MatButton`:

```
<MatBlazor.MatButton Icon="@MatIconNames.Remove_red_eye" OnClick="@ShowData" OnClickStopPropagation="true"></MatBlazor.MatButton>
```